# downloading a file from a page

Tags: python, perl, network-programming, streaming, urllib2

I would like to make a script (in any language, but preferably python or perl) download a specific type of file being streamed by a web page. However i do not know this files location so i will have to find it out by finding all the files being streamed by the page, and selecting the one i want based on file type.

a similar example would be to say i want to download a video off youtube, however there is no pattern or way to find the URL except finding the files being streamed to my computer.

The part i cannot figure out is how to find all the files being streamed by the page. The rest i can do myself. The file name is not mentioned anywhere in the source of the html page.

Example of the problem...

This works fine:

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve ("http://example.com/anything.mp3", "a.mp3")
```

However this does not:

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve ("http://example.com/page-where-the-mp3-file-is-being-streamed.html", "a.mp3")
```

If someone can help me figure out how to download all the files from a page or find the files being streamed i would really appreciate it. **All i need is to know which language/library/method can accomplish this.**Thanks

Comment: Parse the HTML to find what you want to "download"? ... Python has native XML modules and Perl has some good and some reasonable XML parsers, too.

Comment: It has to be mentioned in the source somehow? If not the HTML source, it's referenced from an AJAX call or a secondary file, calls that you can recreate with Python and BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Use the Network tab in Firefox' Firebug addon. It will show all the files being downloaded when you open a page. Once you know what the file is called you can start looking for it in the source and all the js sources. When you know where to look you should be able to do the rest on your own in your favorite language (perl!) =)

Comment: There are many many ways to dynamically create streams or links to streams. It is impractical to enumerate everything. -- Therefore, to make this a better fit for the Stack Overflow format, [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10887751/edit) to improve it: **name the concrete site**, and point out which stream you want to download. Then we can recommend appropriate libraries/code/tools to get at the stream.